# Redis SPOP not atomic?

Tags: redis

Reading the documentation it doesn't look like Set POP (`SPOP`) is atomic, where as `LPOP` and `RPOP`, etc are. This is also what I'm seeing with my code where I have two clients using `lettuce` and reactive streams listening for `SPOP`. When something is pushed, both clients get the same value that was just pushed. I was really hoping to avoid that because I need a set to keep my values unique and was hoping SPOP would be identical to LPOP.

I have a pubsub client that pushes to this Set, and multiple instances will have multiple pubsub clients, which is why the Set to prevent extra work from being done.

I can either make sure list only contains unique items or I can make SPOP atomic. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: SPOP is atomic.

Comment: What @for_stack said.

Comment: @for_stack I can't find anything about this in the spop documentation but lpop and rpop do say they are atomic.

Comment: @stewart99 All of Redis commands are atomic, that is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

There is someone else who explains why SPOP isn't atomic:

https://medium.com/@stockholmux/redis-spop-culture-800cf306cbe6

Comment: I think you misunderstood his scenario. Both `SPOP` and `SADD` are atomic, but if you want to run both commands one after another, that's NOT atomic. Other client might do some operation on the SET between `SPOP` and `SADD`.